# TypeError when trying to retrieve data from Microsoft CRM 2011 REST endpoint via JQuery ajax

Tags: jquery, dynamics-crm-2011

I have the following javascript on the onChange event of a field:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    url: Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl() + "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/rdi_departmentSet(guid'" + departmentId + "')",
    success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
        alert("Success");   
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown.name + " - " + errorThrown.msg + " -- " + textStatus);
    }
});
```

The error callback is firing and I'm getting "TypeError - undefined -- error" in the alert. If I alert what I'm passing in as the url I can browse to it in IE and see the correct results. Any idea what's causing the TypeError?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, I think you're missing the "?" after the "rdi_departmentSet".

Additionally, I always use filter syntax like so: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309461.aspx#BKMK_filter

Comment: Thanks Paul, that's getting me closer. If I use the filter syntax with the department name it works but I'd prefer to use the guid primary key, which I haven't been able to get working.

`?$filter=rdi_name eq 'Law'` works fine, but
`?$filter=rdi_departmentid eq (guid'EA35FB6C-30EE-E111-89B7-00155D630E00')` gives me a 400 error.